# R: ("Automatically") Extract rows based on multiple conditions applied to each row for changing numbers of columns

Tags: r, conditional-statements, extract, rows

In R, I need an automated (the matrix can have a different number of columns, so the headers are not always the same) way  to extract rows from a matrix based on multiple conditions applied individually to each row. Specifically, I want to include a row in a new matrix if all the columns in that row, except the last one, are equal and if the last column in the row is ~= 0.

I cannot go back and change any code besides the input data (ie, everything must run automatically).
The first for loop for diff is calculating differences between corresponding columns in the dataSet, and the next for loop is extracting the rows of diff that satisfy the conditions.

```
Rows=nrow(dataSet)
Cols=ncol(dataSet)
diff <- matrix(, nrow = Rows,ncol = Cols/2)

for (i in 1:Cols/2) {
    diff[,i]=dataSet[,i]-dataSet[,i+Cols/2];
}

last_change <- matrix(, nrow = Rows, ncol = Cols/2); 
T=1;
col1 = ((Cols/2)-1);
col2 = Cols/2;
col3 = 0;
for (k in 1:Rows) {
    if (TRUE==all.equal(diff[k,1],diff[k,2:col1])
      & TRUE==all.equal(diff[k,col2],col3))
    {
     last_change[T,] <- subset(diff[k,]);
     T=T+1; 
     }    
}
```

This above gives me a matrix with the same dimensions as diff (should be equal columns with quite a few rows whittled away) filled with NA's. (I am having trouble vectorizing in an automated way since the $ would have to indicate different numbers and identities of headers every time the input dataSet changes). I am fairly new to R. I have found many questions with similar topics, but none of them seem to encompass the ability to apply multiple conditions to a changing number of columns (and changing identities of colnames).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,1,1,0,2,2,13,0,3,3,3,0,4,4,4,1),4,byrow=T);
m;
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    0
## [2,]    2    2   13    0
## [3,]    3    3    3    0
## [4,]    4    4    4    1
m[apply(m[,-ncol(m)]==m[,1],1,all)&m[,ncol(m)]==0,];
##      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [1,]    1    1    1    0
## [2,]    3    3    3    0
```

Comment: Huge improvement (THANKS)! However, I now get rows with all zeros (makes perfect sense) that have the row name from the prior matrix, and many more rows where each row name and values are <NA> and NA, respectively. Wondering where/how the information may have been lost?

Comment: You can remove rows that have at least one NA value with a single call to `na.omit()`, which can be done either prior to or after the extraction. Row names can be fixed up after-the-fact by assigning them; see https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/colnames.html. For example, `rownames(m2) <- 1:nrow(m2);`.

Comment: No information has been lost; your input matrix must have had NAs.